# How can I prevent jQuery from interfering with my javascript in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have two radio buttons that should assign a value to two separate elements based on which one is active.

Here is the HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input id="Radio1" onclick="radio1click()" name="Radios" type="radio" value="Value 1" checked>
<label for="Radio1">
  Value 1
</label>

<input id="Radio2" onclick="radio2click()" name="Radios" type="radio" value="Value 2">
<label for="Radio2">
  Value 2
</label>

<span id="element-1" valuereada="1">
  Block 1
</span>

<span id="element-2" valuereadb="1">
  Block 2
</span>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
  <script>
  function radio1click() {
    var variable1 = document.getElementById('element-1');
    variable1.setAttribute('valuereada', 1);
    var variable2 = document.getElementById('element-2');
    variable2.setAttribute('valuereadb', 1);

  }
  function radio2click() {
      var variable1 = document.getElementById('element-1');
      variable1.setAttribute('valuereada', 2);
      var variable2 = document.getElementById('element-2');
      variable2.setAttribute('valuereadb', 2);
  }
  </script>
```

When I use the inspect element, I find that these values do change as intended. However, I noticed it stops working after I refresh the browser on Safari and resume testing.

I found the problem is directly attributed to the jQuery dependency. Although I am not using jQuery in the example, it is still finding a way to give me issues. How can I have this work while still keeping the dependency, even though it is not used in the context of this code?

Comment: [Your code works fine, even with jQuery loaded](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/7xmjqs5h/). How did you conclude jQuery is the problem? 
The code you've shown does not use jQuery, so the only way I can think of it being affected by jQuery are: 1) some other jQuery code is interacting with the elements you are working with, or handling clicks, or changing the DOM, etc; or 2) some other jQuery code has some errors, causing all JS to stop working. In either case the problem is not with the code you've shown ...

Comment: That's interesting, it works with jsfiddle but not locally and I tested on multiple machines. I was able to have it work perfectly when I only removed the dependency. jQuery theoretically shouldn't interfere, and I'm just as shocked that it somehow is.